# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for - ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Im Create new Ionic page name for `listing`  and i m added some file its name `listing.service.ts` after  I cant  open this `listing` page i had some error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ListingService!
Error: No provider for ListingService!
```

Im try to fix it for more than one hour but cant  found any solutions , how to fix it ?
Thanks 
**This is my code**

**listing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListingPage } from './listing';
import  {ListingService} from "./listing.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ListingPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ListingPage),
  ],
  providers: [
    ListingService
  ]
})
export class ListingPageModule {}
```

**listing.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 @Injectable()
    export class ListingService {
      private eventMap:any;
      constructor() {
        this.initEventMap();
      }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {ListingService} from "../pages/listing/listing.service";

const providers = [ ListingService ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage




  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CalendarModule, // Ionic Calendar

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: why do you have `const providers = [ ListingService ];` in app.module.ts?

Comment: sir im added listing page to listing.service.ts after i added const providers = [ ListingService ];

Comment: what is the purpose of create providers const variable and assigning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `const providers = [ ListingService ];` in **app.module.ts** but you dont seem to be setting the array anywhere.

If you are using listing.service only in ListingPageModule, you should set it as provider in that module (which you have done.).So remove `listing.service` import in **app.module.ts** as it is outside the module where it is set as provider
.

Comment: Sir something missing for me  providers: [ providers]

Comment: I didnt get you? where are you setting that?

Comment: app.module.ts  > `providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,providers
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]`

Comment: remove `providers` from inside the array.. should be `providers: [ StatusBar, SplashScreen,{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler} ]`. Dont inject twice

Comment: Ok ,sir, im beginner for the Ionic ,Thanks for the guide me